# Angular 4 - How to create Multi-user, Multi master layout template

Tags: typescript-typings, angular4-router

I need to create multiple master layouts for multiple users in Angular 4.

1. Frontend / Client Users
2. Backend / Admin Users

Each of the above use different master templates with their own different header and footer.
Each of the templates use different css and js files.

Currently I am able to only add styles and scripts for 1 particular type (either admin or client).

I put all my template's .css and .js in index.html. It now applies to all pages in the project. I want to make these imports specific to user types.

Following is my project setup

```
--app
  --layouts
    --frontend-header
    --frontend-footer
    --frontend-layout
    --backend-header
    --backend-footer
    --backend-menus
    --backend-settings
  --frontend
    --home
  --backend
    --dashboard
  --login
    --backend-login
    --frontend-login
```

app-routing.module.ts is below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

//Frontend routes goes here
{
    path: '',
    component: FrontendLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    ]
},

//Backend routes goes here here
{
    path: '',
    component: BackendLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'admin/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    ]
},

//no layout routes
{ path: 'login', component: FrontendLoginComponent},
{ path: 'admin/login', component: BackendLoginComponent },
// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }

];
```

Could someone please help me in achieving this?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you want to achieve - do you want to display a completely different tree of components for various user roles?

Comment: @Dan Macák - To put it simply. I'm using AdminLTE for my admin part. For the Client  I use another template. Now the problem is, I'm only able to add css and js files for either one of these templates and not both (possibly because it is applied to the entire application). I want to import them specifically for each type.